# How can we find Python layer log message in Caffe library?

Tags: python, caffe

Caffe library supports self-defined Python layer. In order to debug this layer, one solution is to output some internal variable in the log file, and here is what I did:

```
class MyLayer(caffe.Layer):
   def setup(self,bottom, top):
        import logging
        logging.info("hello the world")
```

In the example, I want to write some strings "hello the world" to the log file.

After the Python layer is defined, we can use "caffe train" program to launch the training. However, I cannot find the Python layer log information in the Caffe log file (in Unbuntu, it is located at /tmp/caffe_username.log.INFO_date). Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use the Google logging `glog` library, like the rest of Caffe. See this [example](https://github.com/pulkitag/caffe-python-layers/blob/master/python_loss_layers.py):

```
import glog

#Simple L1 loss layer
class L1LossLayer(caffe.Layer):

    ...

    def forward(self, bottom, top):
        top[0].data[...] = ...
        glog.info('Loss is %f' % top[0].data[0])
```